# Foundation reveal modal button redirects to url

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have some issues with the foundation reveal button. When i click on the Popup button it goes the the url in place of showing a popup (example.www.website.com/# )

This is my code:

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="firstModal" class="button succes">Popup</a>

<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal>
        <h2>Some Title</h2>

</div>
```

At the end of my code

```
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked if there are any errors in console?

Comment: Include the scripts on top i.e above your code and try

Comment: i found the solution: the "reveal-modal" div must be the first child of the body. otherwise it doesn't work.